# rollback a deployed wsp solution in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, 2010

I have published a solution and deployed it.

```
 Add-SPSolution “C:\Users\Admin\Documents\LeaveManagementPortal.wsp"

 Install-SPSolution –identity "LeaveManagementPortal.wsp" -GACDeployment
```

This deployed the wsp file and there was a list in it as a feature.

when I try to rollback, the lines below work fine when i execute them one after the other.

```
stsadm -o retractsolution -name leavemanagementportal.wsp -immediate
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
stsadm -o deletesolution -name leavemanagementportal.wsp
```

But when I save this as a ps1 file and run it, it throws error

> "the solution cannot be removed when a job is scheduled or running"

The first two line run successfully though. Is the third line trying to execute before the timer job is getting completed? how can i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
stsadm -o retractsolution -name leavemanagementportal.wsp -immediate  
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs  
stsadm -o deletesolution -name leavemanagementportal.wsp
```

The above mentioned code is a stsadm command line tool and you can try it as a `.bat` save file instead of `.ps1` file. Also you need to write the code for stop and start [ restart ] the `SP Admin Services` and `SP Timer Services` and you must provide few seconds as an interval[tell the function to `sleep` for 5 or 8 seconds until the timer services restarted] to restart the `services`.

For the purpose of rollback and other operations related to `WSP` files, its better you to take the `ISE PowerShell` approach and save this as a `.ps1` file and deploy. This has a  `waitfortimer` function and `sleep` to perform rollback/deploy `WSP`

Refer  [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b06da204-bd66-4143-9c12-e400cd1952e1/deploy-wsp-through-power-shell-start-stop-sp-admin-service-and-run-execadmsvcjobs-command-using?forum=sharepointdevelopment)  link and   [this](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Deploy-a-SharePoint-2013-Solution-(WSP)-in-the-Farm-using-PowerShell)

Answer (score 4):

I always use the below PowerShell script to Uninstall and delete SpSolutions:

```
add-pssnapin "microsoft.sharepoint.powershell"
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
echo " "
echo "Uninstalling YourSolutionName"
$sln = get-spsolution -identity YourSolutionName.wsp 
uninstall-spsolution -identity YourSolutionName.wsp -confirm:$false
echo "Started solution retraction..." 
while($sln.JobExists) { 
echo " > Uninstall in progress..."
start-sleep -s 10 
}
remove-spsolution -identity YourSolutionName.wsp -confirm:$false
echo "Removed YourSolutionName"
echo "  "
```

Run this PS1 and you are set.